# Play framework set download file name

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm returning a file from a controller, via play.mvc.Results.ok(file). However, the file downloads as "download", without a specific file name. Is there a way I can set the name for the download (i.e. image.png)?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

In order to define a specific filename, you have to set a `Content-Disposition` header in the response before returning the `ok(file)` Result.

Here is a sample code :

```
public static Result myAction() {
    ...
    response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=image.png");
    return ok(file);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The magic for this in Scala (Play 2.4.x) is

```
def myAction() {
    ...
    ok(file).withHeaders("Content-Disposition" -> "attachment; filename=image.png")
}
```

Notice that it's plural, its a map and you can have multiple values if needed.

Of course the next thing you'll want to do is make it an actual download which is done like so:

```
def myAction() {
    ...
    ok(file).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/x-download",  CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "attachment; filename=image.png")
}
```

Notice there are CONSTANTS for most headers defined in Controller  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Controller